# C# winfom htmleditor - WYSIWYG

Tags: c#, winforms, wysiwyg

I need a WYSIWYG html editor like [**ckeditor**](http://ckeditor.com/demo) or [niceedit](http://nicedit.com/demos.php) for **C# winform applications**. so that user can edit html then I insert it in database.

is there any WYSIWYG for C# winform applications?
tnx

Answer (score 3):

Just put one of the above editors in a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control and you're done.

Comment: i tried to put niceedit in webbrowser by webBrowser1.DocumentText. it doesnt work. and if I can, then have can I save the htl that user entered??? with webBrowser1.DocumentText ??

Comment: It's a bit old now but there's an example of doing that here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27586/tinyMCE-HTML-Editor-in-NET-WindowsForms

Answer (score 3):

The Netrix Component, the most sophisticated WinForm HTML editing control, is now available on Github as **Open Source** for non-commercial usage. This includes all Plug-Ins available, such as Spell Checker, Table Designer and so on.

https://github.com/joergkrause/netrix

This project was a commercial project for more than ten years and meanwhile it's mature, stable, and feature complete. However, the traction of the WinForm world slows down and we think that it will prolong the project's life if we make it publicly available.

Comment: Also the download doesn't work :( http://i.imgur.com/VLMX8vb.png

Comment: The commercial version may be obtained from here:https://www.componentsource.com/product/netrix-professional

Comment: Component Source is no longer selling the control. Because WinForms components are going to get only few sales these days I handle this directly. If one needs a commercial license please write me directly. As the inventor and developer I can still offer a package with code, sources, support, and the right terms and conditions. Drop me an email or use the form at www.joergkrause.de.

Comment: @JoergKrause How to install netrix? https://github.com/joergkrause/netrix/issues/3

Comment: This is just the source code, there is no installation. It compiles into a bunch of WinForms component, you can add to any WinForms project.

Answer (score 2):

You can try .NET WinForms HTML Editor Control from SpiceLogic. It is easy to use, ready to go out of the box commercial component sports with lots of features and extensibility.

https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/NET-WinForms-HTML-Editor-Control-8

[image: SpiceLogic .NET WinForms HTML Editor Control]

Comment: Nice but starts at $450